# Adding a custom HTML block to a view

Tags: views, blocks

I have a view in Drupal 8 that looks as follows (see screenshot). To make the long story short, I need to make this view output a fixed HTML block (piece of code, not Drupal Block) and not pull any dynamic data from the respective content type.

What is the most efficient way of doing this?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In your screen shot, there is **HEADER** and **FOOTER** section. Click add in one of them and add a `Global: Text Area`, and put your HTML there, for text filter use `FULL HTML`.

[image]

Comment: Why make it difficult if you can K.I.S.S., right?

Answer (score 1):

Output the block to the page. View the HTML source for the page. Copy the HTML for the block.

If you want to display the block on the site, then create a new block through the admin interface, and paste the HTML there.

Comment: I already have the HTML that I would like the view to display. Could you give a more step-by-step instructions on how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

If it helps anyone, what i ended up doing was creating a new custom Block in Drupal and pasting the needed HTML there as Full HTML format. I then placed this new Block in place of the View in question on the needed page. I did the latter on the Block Layout page.